# How to Add New Rows and Fill with "0" in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to help a colleague out with their spreadsheets (on MAC Excel V16.16.8), since I have some experience with coding, mostly in SQL, only very very basic level of VBA.

They receive daily data (which is why VBA is needed) which I have managed to split into separate sheets for them using basic macros.

[image: Here is a screenshot of an example of what one sheet contains]

The name of the sheet is "Birmingham" in this example.

Column B "Interval" are the hours of the day (24 hour clock). They only receive any data for the hours of the day where data actually exists in other columns. However, for their reports, they need to add/insert new rows even where there isn't any data from 0-23 (midnight-11pm).

The "Interval" column needs the correct hour/number in this descending order as seen in the example, with the `Date` and `Campaign` columns just being the same throughout. And have the rest of the cells for `Total_Calls`, `Closed`, etc, containing "0"s.

How do I add the new rows, "Intervals", and the "0"s?

I have tried a couple of different ways mostly around attempting to merge a mostly blank separate table only containing all of the "Intervals" 0-23. However, I have failed miserably in each method.

I am almost 100% sure there is a relatively simple method of doing this, but I lack specific VBA knowledge.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, a collaborative website for answering *specific* coding issues.  If you could rephrase your post to have a specific question.  In its current form your question leads to a subjective response, when the goal is to have objective answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current date and current campaign and insert missing rows like this:

```
Private Sub FillAllHours()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myDate As Date      ' value from date column
    Dim myCampain As String ' value from campaign column

    With ActiveSheet
        myDate = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value
        myCampain = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Value
        For i = 2 To 25
            If .Cells(i, "B") <> i - 2 Then ' if row is missing
                .Rows(i).Insert             ' insert row above
                .Cells(i, "B") = i - 2      ' insert hour number
                .Cells(i, "A") = myDate     ' insert date
                .Cells(i, "C") = mycampaign ' insert campaign
                .Cells(i, "D").Resize(1, 9).Value = 0 ' fill 9 cells with 0
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tested this and it has worked perfectly so far. You have made mine and my colleagues day! Thanks. I did not think to go about it this way at all. Will let you know if I encounter any issues. Cheers!